# Runtime error while trying to add admob

Tags: java, android, admob

This error keeps popping up, while I'm trying to add admob in my finished app:

11-16 11:20:00.452: E/AndroidRuntime(29463): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ch.swegup.lecontroll/ch.swegup.sambadance.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView

**This is the xml file:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="c...y"
    >
    <com.facebook.widget.LikeView
        android:id="@+id/lvLike"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <com.google.ads.AdView 
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"    
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-0697264956871753/3628628847E"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    />
```

**and this the java:**

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;
import com.facebook.AppEventsLogger;
import com.facebook.Settings;
import com.facebook.widget.LikeView;
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private AdView adView;
    private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-0697264956871753/3628628847E";

    //UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
    TextView textView;
//  Button buttonende;
    Button tipps;
    Button btn1;
    Button rate;

    LikeView LikeView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tipps = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tipps);
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSTART);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
        rate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rate);
        rate.setOnClickListener(this);

        // Create the adView.
        adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);



        // Lookup your RelativeLayoutLayout assuming it’s been given     
        // the attribute android:id="@+id/ad"     

        // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad     
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        // Start loading the ad in the background.
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are confusing com.google.ads.AdView with com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView. You have asked for one in your XML but are expecting the other in your code.

You should use com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView for both as this is the AdView from GooglePlayServices.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code which creates the adView to this:

```
adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
```

and remove the following lines:

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.adView);     
layout.addView(adView);
```

**UPDATE**:

Try to change your xml tag from com.google.android.Adview to

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
```

Also, you should remove loadAdOnCreate attribute since it is no longer available in Google play services.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/play-migration

Hope this helps.

Comment: @EmanuelGraf you should use Google Play Services, not Android SDK. I updated my answer.

Comment: It works thx. but now i get this error: 11-16 12:29:15.902: W/Ads(2944): There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 1
11-16 12:29:15.952: W/Ads(2944): Failed to load ad: 1

Comment: @EmanuelGraf Glad to hear that it works. Error code 1 is ERROR_CODE_INVALID_REQUEST which means the ad unit ID is incorrect.  Check your ad unit ID if it is valid.

Comment: thx dude :DD now one more question: Is this code with this ad stable? I mean, i'm starting advertising this app today and it would be a little bit fail, if it wouldn't work... so the question: can I rollout this version to 100%?

Comment: Well..I cannot say since I didn't see your app's full source code. Make sure you test your app enough before publishing on the market. Please accept my answer if your code works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Excellent little tutorial here i came across while trying to implement admob myself, i think its by far the best and easiest way to do it.

http://blog.blundell-apps.com/migrating-to-admob-in-google-play-services-from-admob-sdk-jar/